# Replacing the Toshiba Startup Splashscreen/Logo with the default Windows 8 Logo

Tags: windows-8, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-A preloaded with Windows 8. Instead of the Windows 8 Logo, it has the Toshiba Logo on the loading screen when I first turn my laptop on.

I don't like this and would rather see the Windows 8 logo when I start my computer. Is there anyway I can switch the logo so that I do not have to see the Toshiba logo anymore?

Comment: It's probably a feature you can disable in BIOS. Does it go from that logo to the "Starting Windows..." one?

Comment: No it just Shows the Toshiba Logo with the windows 8 circle thing that shows something is loading then it takes me to my lock screen

Answer (score 0):

To change this Logo for my Dell Laptop, I had to turn off fast boot by selecting the option to load `VGA Option ROM` in the UEFI.